# Jquery hide/show div when dropdownlistfor is change, MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

this is my _Layout.cshtml, the body section

```js
@RenderBody()

    @if (IsSectionDefined("Scripts"))
    {
        @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
    }

    @section Scripts{
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery-3.3.1.js")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery-3.3.1.min.js")

        <script>
            function hideOnLoad() {
                $('#OtherPurposeFormGroup').hide();
            }

            function showOnSelect() {
                $('#OtherPurposeFormGroup').show();
            }

            $(document).ready(function () {
                hideOnLoad();
                $('#SelectPurposeID').change(function () {
                    var value = $(this).val();
                    if (value == '32') {
                        showOnSelect();
                    }
                    else {
                        hideOnLoad();
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    }
```

now here is the create.cshtml as partial view

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Clearance.Purpose, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })&nbsp;(<b style="color: #ff0000;">*</b>)
                        <br>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Clearance.Purpose, listItems, "", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "SelectPurposeID" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Clearance.Purpose, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4" id="OtherPurposeFormGroup">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Clearance.OtherPurpose, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })&nbsp;(<b style="color: #ff0000;">*</b>)
                        <br>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Clearance.OtherPurpose, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "OtherPurposeID" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Clearance.OtherPurpose, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
```

i'm trying to hide the div with Id OtherPurposeID upon page load, then when i select in the dropdownlistfor the "Other Purpose" (with 32 as id in database) the div OtherPurposeID will show.

jquery is also included in the bundle, in script folder, also in the section script.

how or why the jquery script is not working?

(edit:)
i also tried looking if there's any error in javascript in chrome browser using f12, it's not showing any error at all.
also, when page loads, the other purposes div is visible. even simple .hide() is not working

Comment: Did you check the page rendering the scripts or not? share the rendered html code...

Comment: @Karthik how do i checked that part?

Comment: You can check that via developer tools... or simply right click on the page (once page loaded in browser) and select view source from the menu... then you can check the source code whether all scripts loaded or not...